Select query with multi conditions from one table
I have this table

and I made a query to collect the totals :
SELECT
    SaleID,
    UserID,
    SUM(SaleQuantity) AS TOTALQNTY,
    SUM(SaleFinalPrice * SaleQuantity) AS FINALPRICE
FROM
    xxxtemp
GROUP BY
    UserID;


What I want is to collect the totals when
SaleInOut = 'in'
and when
SaleInOut = 'out'
I tried this query :
SELECT
    SaleID,
    UserID,
    CASE WHEN SaleInOut = 'in' THEN SUM(SaleQuantity)
END AS TOTALQNTYIN,
CASE WHEN SaleInOut = 'in' THEN SUM(SaleFinalPrice * SaleQuantity)
END AS FINALPRICEIN,
CASE WHEN SaleInOut = 'out' THEN SUM(SaleQuantity)
END AS TOTALQNTYOUT,
CASE WHEN SaleInOut = 'out' THEN SUM(SaleFinalPrice * SaleQuantity)
END AS FINALPRICEOUT
FROM
    xxxtemp
GROUP BY
    UserID;

and the result :

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated...
Thank you in advance
Regards,

Please read : Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Your expressions should be SUM(CASE condition THEN value ELSE NULL END)

That's it,, thank you

Change your query as follows:
SELECT
    SaleID,
    UserID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SaleInOut = 'in'  THEN SaleQuantity                    END) AS TOTALQNTYIN,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SaleInOut = 'out' THEN SaleQuantity                    END) AS TOTALQNTYOUT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SaleInOut = 'in'  THEN (SaleFinalPrice * SaleQuantity) END) AS FINALPRICEIN,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SaleInOut = 'out' THEN (SaleFinalPrice * SaleQuantity) END) AS FINALPRICEOUT
FROM
    xxxtemp
GROUP BY
    UserID;

Thank You

Perfect,, I missed this ... Thank you
